# stripe function is calling again and again and token is changing repeatedly?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, stripe-payments

Help me to find an error in the stripe payment where the token is changing repeatedly in inspect element seems like function is calling again and again? Can anyone tell me where is the problem? Help me to find an error in the stripe payment where the token is changing repeatedly in inspect element seems like function is calling again and again? Can anyone tell me where is the problem?

```
**stripe.blade.php**

@extends('layouts.user')
@section('title', 'Stripe Payment')
@section('content')

<div class="container my-5">
  
  
    <div class="row my-5">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 my-5">
            <div class="panel panel-default credit-card-box">
                <div class="panel-heading display-table" >
                    <div class="row display-tr" >
                        <h3 class="panel-title display-td" >Payment Details</h3>
                        <div class="display-td" >                            
                            <a href="{{url('user/stripe')}}"><img src="{{url('assets/user/img/payment.png')}}" alt=""></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>                    
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
  
                    @if (Session::has('success'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success text-center">
                            <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">×</a>
                            <p>{{ Session::get('success') }}</p>
                        </div>
                    @endif
  
                    <form role="form" action="{{url('user/stripe')}}" method="post" class="require-validation" data-cc-on-file="false"
                     data-stripe-publishable-key="{{ env('STRIPE_KEY') }}" id="payment-form">
                        @csrf
                        <input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" id="stripeToken" value="">
                        <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{ Auth::user()->id }}">
                        <div class='form-row row'>
                            <div class='col-xs-12 form-group required'>
                                <label class='control-label'>Name on Card</label> <input
                                    class='form-control' name='card_name' size='4' type='text'>
                            </div>
                        </div>
  
                        <div class='form-row row'>
                            <div class='col-xs-12 form-group card required'>
                                <label class='control-label'>Card Number</label> <input
                                    autocomplete='off' name='card_number' class='form-control card-number' size='20'
                                    type='text'>
                            </div>
                        </div>
  
                        <div class='form-row row'>
                            <div class='col-xs-12 col-md-4 form-group cvc required'>
                                <label class='control-label'>CVC</label> <input autocomplete='off'
                                    class='form-control card-cvc' name='cvc' placeholder='ex. 311' size='4'
                                    type='text'>
                            </div>
                            <div class='col-xs-12 col-md-4 form-group expiration required'>
                                <label class='control-label'>Expiration Month</label> <input
                                    class='form-control card-expiry-month' name='exp_month' placeholder='MM' size='2'
                                    type='text'>
                            </div>
                            <div class='col-xs-12 col-md-4 form-group expiration required'>
                                <label class='control-label'>Expiration Year</label> <input
                                    class='form-control card-expiry-year' name='exp_year' placeholder='YYYY' size='4'
                                    type='text'>
                            </div>
                        </div>
  
                        <div class='form-row row'>
                            <div class='col-md-12 error form-group hide'>
                                <div class='alert-danger alert'>Please correct the errors and try
                                    again.</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
  
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">Pay Now ($100)</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>    
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>        
        </div>
    </div>   
</div>
  
</body>

@endsection

@section('user_specific_js')

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var $form = $(".require-validation");
     $('form.require-validation').bind('submit', function(e) {
          var $form = $(".require-validation"),
               inputSelector = ['input[type=email]', 'input[type=password]',
                         'input[type=text]', 'input[type=file]',
                         'textarea'].join(', '),
          $inputs = $form.find('.required').find(inputSelector),
          $errorMessage = $form.find('div.error'),
          valid = true;
          $errorMessage.addClass('hide');
          $('.has-error').removeClass('has-error');
    
          $inputs.each(function(i, el) {
          var $input = $(el);
          if ($input.val() === '') {
              $input.parent().addClass('has-error');
              $errorMessage.removeClass('hide');
              e.preventDefault();
          }
    });
  
    if (!$form.data('cc-on-file')) {
      e.preventDefault();
      Stripe.setPublishableKey($form.data('stripe-publishable-key'));
      Stripe.createToken({
        number: $('.card-number').val(),
        cvc: $('.card-cvc').val(),
        exp_month: $('.card-expiry-month').val(),
        exp_year: $('.card-expiry-year').val()
      }, stripeResponseHandler);
    }
  
  });
  
  function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {
        if (response.error) {
            $('.error')
                .removeClass('hide')
                .find('.alert')
                .text(response.error.message);
        } else {
            // token contains id, last4, and card type
            var token = response['id'];
            // insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
            $form.find('input[type=text]').empty();
            $('#stripeToken').val(token);
            $('#payment-form').submit();
            
        }
    }
  
});
</script>

@endsection



**CheckoutController**


<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Stripe;


class CheckoutController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * success response method.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function stripe()
    {
        return view('user.stripe');
    }
  
    /**
     * success response method.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function stripePost(Request $request)
    {
        Log::info(print_r($request->all, true));

        Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(env('STRIPE_SECRET'));
        $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create([
            'email' => $request->user()->email,
            'payment_method' => $request->input('stripeToken'),
            'invoice_settings' => [
              'default_payment_method' => $request->input('stripeToken'),
            ],
        ]);


        Log::info("Create Customer Response");
        Log::info(print_r($customer, true));
        
        Session::flash('success', 'Payment successful!');

        return back();
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like `if (!$form.data('cc-on-file')) {` could be the cause.

Comment: still same problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to narrow down the scope of the problem by disabling code until you isolate the error.

It looks like you have a loop triggered by `$('#payment-form').submit();` Since you also bind the `submit` action on `form.require-validation`:

```
$('form.require-validation').bind('submit'...
```

and then inside that you invoke `stripeResponseHandler` which again fires `$('#payment-form').submit()`.

You need to break this cycle.